# Pycharm Console crash after Ctrl+C

Tags: python, pycharm

When using the interactive Python console in Pycharm (community edition 2017.1.5), the console crashes when using a keyboard interrupt <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Let's say the program is stuck in a very long operation that I want to stop. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> the execution actually stops, but the console crashes if I try any other operation on the console.

This is the error I am receiving:

[image]

Any idea how can I solve this? I just want to continue working on the same console after a Keyboard Interrupt.

Comment: You should probably look for this answer on Jetbraims' website. They have a good issue tracker and support.

Comment: but Pycharm has it's own "Ctrl-C" and "Terminate" buttons in console. You should use them, because sending "Ctrl+C" send SIGINT to pycharm console, not to the stuck program

Comment: can you please elaborate on this? (also as answer if you prefer)

Comment: sorry, disregard, 'Ctrl+C' button is inactive in console and "Terminate" button  kills console itself

Comment: @FLab same problem here... did you hind a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The problem disappeared after updating to PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.3, hence I believe it was some sort of bug in the 1.5 version.

Answer (score -1):

Using PyCharm

1. CRTL+F2 to stop 'app'
2. ALT+Shift+F10 to run the app again.
3. Refresh your web browser page.

NOTE: Using Google Chrome hold down the CTRL button while you click the Chrome Refresh button to perform a complete 100% page refresh.